# How do I declare new type with type constraints in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I’m tring to declare a new type Value as below:

```
data Value m = Wrong | Num Int | Fun (Value -> m Value)
```

And GHCI complains:

```
<interactive>:160:39:
    Expecting one more argument to ‘Value’
    Expected a type, but ‘Value’ has kind ‘k0 -> *’
    In the type ‘Value -> m Value’
    In the definition of data constructor ‘Fun’
    In the data declaration for ‘Value’
```

PS: I'm trying to implement code of [`The essence of functional programming`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuJGO.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Value` takes a type parameter, you need to supply that parameter any time you use `Value`. That is, you should refer to it as `Value m`, not just `Value`. So your type definition should be:

```
data Value m = Wrong | Num Int | Fun ((Value m) -> m (Value m))
```

Comment: `Value` used to be a type which was only defined for a single type constructor `M` with kind `* -> *`. You are generalizing `Value` to be a type constructor itself, but one that takes a value of kind `* -> *` instead of a concrete type. This means you need to apply `Value` to `m` *everywhere* in the definition so that your definition kind-checks.